# Delete element in associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a button so that when clicked, a specific element stored in an associative array will get deleted. But what I've done doesn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  // Creates the button
  bodyText = bodyText + '<input type="button" id="btnDeleteQuestion" 
  value="Delete a question">';

  document.getElementById("btnDeleteQuestion")
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Deletes the third question stored in the questionBank
      delete questionBank[2]['questionText'];
      console.log(questionBank);  
    });
}
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? What is `bodyText`? Are you missing some code here? What's the format of `questionBank`?

Comment: Is `questionBank` an array or an ojbect?

Comment: Its an array not an object

Answer (score 1):

Use `splice` (if it is an array) to remove the element from the array.

```
questionBank.splice(2, 1); // from the third element, remove 1 item.
```

What you have written in your question will get the `questionBank[2]` and then delete a `property` called `questionText` in the object.

It will also throw an error if the array does not have at least 3 items or if the 3rd item is `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you helpful this

```
var questionBank= ["questionText", "questionText1", "questionText2"];
document.getElementById("btnDeleteQuestion").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // index get by text         
    const index = questionBank.indexOf("questionText");   
    if(index!=-1){  
         //Delete element by index
          questionBank.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(questionBank);  
});
```